# sql update and join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update

I have a table (in phpmyadmin) that i want to update.

The table is called categories, which has fields ID, Name & sid

I want to update the Name column with the value contained in the table called vocabulary.

Vocabulary contains sid, langid & value

I have worked out the select join statement as follows:

```
Select categories.ID, vocabulary.value
FROM categories
Inner join vocabulary
on categories.sid = vocabulary.sid
where langid = 1;
```

However, as i said, i want to update the name field in categories with the corrosponding value from vocabulary.

So i have tried a number of queries but none seem to work

```
Update categories
set cateogires.Name = vocabulary.value
Inner join vocabulary
on categories.sid = vocabulary.sid
where langid = 1;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `INNER JOIN` is part of the `UPDATE` clause in `MySQL` (*you have mentioned phpmyadmin*).

```
UPDATE  Categories a
        INNER JOIN Vocabulary b
            ON a.sid = b.sid
SET     a.Name = b.value
WHERE   b.langID = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Is there any other ways to achieve this as it is taking forever and making my db hang. It is working but very slowly, whereas my first select statement completes in seconds. Thanks again for your help

Comment: is the value of `Vocabulary.sid` always references on `Categories.sid`, if that's the case execute the following statement, `ALTER TABLE VOCABULARY ADD CONSTRAINT voc_fk FOREIGN KEY (sid) REFERENCES Categories(sid)`. make sure `Categories.sid` is a primary key or there's an index defined on the column.

Comment: @user2231688 if the above is not correct, execute the following `ALTER TABLE Categories ADD INDEX (sid)`, `ALTER TABLE Vocabularies ADD INDEX (sid)`